# How to install Ubuntu Touch on unofficial cyanogenmod ports

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

I have a Samsung Galaxy S Plus i9001 and I would like to install Ubuntu Touch on it, but my device is not officially supported by cyanogenmod. Anyway a port exists and also some derived roms (like ehndroix). If exists, what is the path to create a working ubuntu-touch build for my device?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should find a compatible CyanogenMod for your device and install that on your device to get the binary "blobs", which are the core parts of the Android kernel and the drivers.
Then you should edit those and/or their configuration files to be compatible with Ubuntu Touch.

Here is possible to find a complete HOW-TO:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting#Building_the_Android_pieces

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recent guide I did for the Galaxy S4 - however most parts should be applicable for other Samsung handsets - just get the right ROM for your device.

http://www.gaggl.com/2013/07/installing-custom-rom-on-galaxy-s4-international-from-ubuntu/

HTH !